# Stack address not corresponding (Trying to understand Buffer overflow)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, stack-overflow

I have been following this tutorial at http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html but at example3.c my function return address doesn't correspond to the logic he implies. I can understand how the return address can be changed at a function but doing it on my computer just doesn't do the trick. I have used -fno-stack-protector and gdb with info registers and disassemble main and also disassemble the function but to no avail. I'm kinda new to Assembly.
My computer is running xubuntu 14 32bits.
My gcc instruction is:  gcc -Wall -ansi -g -fno-stack-protector example3.c

```
example3.c:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
   int *ret;

   ret = buffer1 + 12;
   (*ret) += 8;
}

void main() {
  int x;

  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n",x);
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

gdb disassemble on main with a breakpoint on function call

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804843b <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804843c <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804843e <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048441 <+6>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x08048444 <+9>: movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
=> 0x0804844c <+17>:    movl   $0x3,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048454 <+25>:    movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804845c <+33>:    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
   0x08048463 <+40>:    call   0x804841d <function>
   0x08048468 <+45>:    movl   $0x1,0x1c(%esp)
   0x08048470 <+53>:    mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048474 <+57>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048478 <+61>:    movl   $0x8048520,(%esp)
   0x0804847f <+68>:    call   0x80482f0 <printf@plt>
   0x08048484 <+73>:    leave  
   0x08048485 <+74>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.


(gdb) disassemble function 
Dump of assembler code for function function:
   0x0804841d <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804841e <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048420 <+3>: sub    $0x20,%esp
=> 0x08048423 <+6>: lea    -0x9(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048426 <+9>: add    $0xc,%eax
   0x08048429 <+12>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x0804842c <+15>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804842f <+18>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048431 <+20>:    lea    0x8(%eax),%edx
   0x08048434 <+23>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048437 <+26>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x08048439 <+28>:    leave  
   0x0804843a <+29>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

At line 9 of function, *ret points to a completely different address

```
9     (*ret) += 8;
(gdb) p/x *ret
$1 = 0x48468c7 (already with the + 8)
```

So to clarify, this program is supose to print 0 since the return was changed to jump over the x = 1 instruction.

My question is, why isn't *ret pointing to an address that is somewhat close to main's corresponding addresses?

I'm sorry for my English.

Best regards,
Vcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tutorial is about some very old compiler.

Lets handle experiment (say gcc 4.8.1, 64-bit Win32) with identical results:

Step 1. Identify where function really starts:

```
(gdb) disassemble function
Dump of assembler code for function function:
=> 0x00000000004014f0 <+0>:     push   %rbp
```

Step 2. Store somewhere its address and break here

```
(gdb) b *0x00000000004014f0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4014f0: file test3.c, line 1.
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, function (a=1, b=4200201, c=4) at test3.c:1
1       void function(int a, int b, int c) {
```

Step 3. Okay, here we are. Lets explore where do our return address stored:

```
(gdb) p $rsp
$1 = (void *) 0x22fe18
(gdb) x 0x22fe18
0x22fe18:       0x0040154c
```

Wow. Lets check inside main:

```
0x0000000000401547 <+36>:    callq  0x4014f0 <function>
0x000000000040154c <+41>:    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
```

Step 4. Looks like we found it. Store somewhere value of $rsp=0x22fe18 and now lets see what is buffer starts:

```
7          (*ret) += 8;
(gdb) p &buffer1[0] 
$2 = 0x22fe00 "`\035L"
```

So buffer[0] address is 0x22fe18 - 0x22fe00 = 0x18 from our target. Not 0xc, as in your example, uh-oh.

P.S. On your compiler and OS, and your optimization options it might be not 0x18, but other value. Try. Experiment. Being hacker is about experimenting, not about running someones scripts.

Good luck.

Comment: "Experiment. Being hacker is about experimenting, not about running someones scripts." I understand that, but i need to understand what im doing first, I'm sorry, but i was thought to first think then do, not the other way around, and by starting with this script i was trying to understand assembly. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: I outlined thinking process. You must calculate correct offset first, then overwrite it. What's unclear?

Comment: Nothing is unclear I'm sorry, your answer is perfect. I was offended by your comment, because i understand what a script kid is. But that's my problem. Nevermind it.

Comment: My apologizes. My intention was to inspire, not to offend.